# How to implement cross-application autofill in Android?

Tags: android

we need to develop an application with ability to enter anything to inputs of another applications.
It may sound confusing, there is lastpass android app that does what we need — http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFVLzqju4wQ

How did they do it? We dont need step by step manual, just directions for further investigation, which sections of andoid api we have to read to implement this?

And is it possible to do using phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How did they do it?

As you can tell by watching the video, they used [the accessibility API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#act-for-users). Presumably, they are using `performAction()` with `ACTION_PASTE` to automate filling in the fields.

> And is it possible to do using phonegap?

Unlikely. At best, somebody could write a plugin for it.